# How to make sure an IEC power extension cable is working properly?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have an SFF PC case ([Lian Li A4H2O](https://i.pcmag.com/imagery/reviews/03d8wHhHJQg28dmOpgAcXc0-19.fit_lim.size_768x.jpg)) that has an [extension cable](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/IMAGERENDERING_521856-T1/images/I/31-lh9pR1XL.jpg) inside it.

I also have strong suspicions that my PC is not functioning properly because of it, as bypassing the extension seemingly sovles the issue (still testing).

I have done thorough testing to elliminate other possible causes for the problem and this extension cable is one of the remaining few that's left.

How can i check to see if the cable is not damaged in some way and is functional?

Thank you.

Comment: Functional - it sounds like you are achieving this through a process of elimination so, what else is needed to be done?

Comment: What does "not function properly" even means? While possible, it is hard to imagine how bad a mains extension cable must be to affect the operation of a PC.

Comment: @Justme The HDD (and only HDD) keeps randomly disconnecting.
It's not to do with overheating (it's well under the temp limit), overloading (it disconnects even when it's not being utilized at all), lacking the required wattage (used to work fine before), bad SATA cables (swapped a bunch), bad mobo (got a new one) or do with the HDD itself (works fine on a different PC). Seeing how the case was the last remaining component introduced before the issue appeared, i'm thinking it's to do with the extension. I'm not an expert, so forgive me if my line of reasoning sounds uneducated - it is.

Comment: @Andyaka The problem is that sometimes the computer can work fine for multiple days in a row without the issue being present and i would like to try and pin it down quicker than that, so that's why i'm asking if there is a way i can test the extension to make 100% sure if that's the root of the problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred method is **disconnect the cable from everything**, then use a continuity checker on each of the live, neutral, and earth connections.

The proper test is every pair of pins, 15 measurements:

1. Measure (L1-L2, N1-N2, E1,E2) should all have very low resistrance.
2. Check for shorts at one end (L1-N1, L1-E1, N1-E1)
3. Check for shorts at the other end (L2-N2, L2-E2, N2-E2)
4. And shorts or crosses along the wire (L1-N2, L1-E2, N1-L2, N1-E2, E1-L2, E1-N2).

If mechanically it looks robust and all electrical tests succeed, yes it's good.

Comment: Would testing for continuity suffice? I.e. if there is, in fact, continuity between each of the connections - can i rest assured that the cable is fine?

Comment: The proper test is every pair of pins (L1-L2, N1-N2, E1,E2) should all have very low resistrance.  Check for shorts at one end (L1-N1, L1-E1, N1-E1) the other end (L2-N2, L2-E2, N2-E2) and along the wire (L1-N2, L1-E2, N1-L2, N1-E2, E1-L2, E1-N2).  If mechanically it looks robust and all electrical tests succeed, yes it's good.